# Require_once failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, require-once

I have this error:

> Warning: require_once(../questionTypes/Question.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u949913003/public_html/includes/essential.php on line 25
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../questionTypes/Question.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.6/pear') in /home/u949913003/public_html/includes/essential.php on line 25

I require essential.php from New_test.php like this:

```
require_once('../essential.php');
```

Then in essential.php, I require Question.php like this:

```
require_once($config['systemQuestionTypesClassDir'].'Question.php');
```

`$config` is defined in config.php:

```
$config['controller']['a'] = 'Admin';
$config['controller']['e'] = 'Teacher';
$config['controller']['t'] = 'Teacher';
$config['controller']['s'] = 'Student';
$config['controller']['at'] = 'Teacher';
$config['controller']['er'] = 'Teacher';
// System directories
$config['systemControllersDir'] = '../controllers/';
$config['systemQuestionTypesClassDir'] = '../questionTypes/';
$config['systemViewsDir'] = '../views/';
$config['systemLibsDir'] = 'libs/';
$config['systemLangsDir'] = 'langs/';
$config['systemQuestionTypesLibDir'] = $config['systemLibsDir'].question;
$config['systemLangsXml'] = '../resources/languages/';
$config['systemExtraDir'] = = 'extra/';
$config['systemFpdfDir'] = 'fpdf/';
$config['systemPhpGraphLibDir'] = 'phpgraphlib—master/';
$config['systemFileManagerDir'] = 'filemanager/';
```

My folders structure is this:

[image]

Obviously in questionTypes there is Question.php.

I don't know ho to solve this.

Comment: try: 
require_once(dirname( /__FILE/__ ).'/../essential.php'); (note: there are no backslashes in FILE)

Comment: that gives the same error

Answer (score 3):

Calling "include" from another "include" could cause problems when they are relative paths. If you use the absolute path, it shouldn't be a problem.

You could use `__DIR__` to get the directory that contains the file where this is written.

I think this should works:

File: `New_test.php`

```
require_once(__DIR__ .'/../essential.php');
```

File: `essential.php`

```
require_once(__DIR__ .'/../questionTypes/Question.php');
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't change essential.php file, I can only work on New_test.php because the file essential.php is related to a site that actually work